# "The tool not licensed" ERROR on a geoprocessing service on ArcGIS Server 10.1

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, error-000824

I have a python script which runs well as geoprocesing tool. When published on ArcGIS Server 10.1 as geoprocessing service, however, it throws the following error:

```
Unable to complete operation.
Error executing tool.: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed. Failed to execute (Kriging). Failed to execute (NewCuringModelExpPy). Failed to execute (New_Curing_Model_ExpPy).
```

The script runs without any error on ArcCatalog with Spatial Analyst extension authorized. The code also has got proper license checked out as below:

```
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
```

I don't think ArcGIS Server requires Spatial Analyst extension authorized, does it? Otherwise, is it to do with any ArcGIS Server configuration?

By the way, I am running on ArcGIS Server 10.1 Advanced so Spatial Analyst extension should have been part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect that you would need to authorise these extensions for every individual Esri product.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I am already with ArcGIS for Server 10.1 sp1 Advanced. Isn't Spatial Analyst included? In addition, ArcGIS Desktop is also installed on the same machine with SA authorized already.

Comment: I thought Spatial Analyst should have been part of ArcGIS Server 10.1 Advanced version. This is stated in the ArcGIS Server 10.1 Help as well.

Answer (score 4):

As you say, Spatial Analyst is included in ArcGIS for Server Advanced according to this [White Paper](http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-server-functionality-matrix.pdf) so I suspect that the license codes may just have not been installed.

Try to trace back to who installed your ArcGIS for Server licenses and check that they installed all licenses provided by Esri.

Comment: Thanks very much. It's fixed by me authorizing Spatial Server extension on ArcServer.